# Get the last Valid Value of day in a date using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I have this code :

```
//Set Delivery Date based from Request Date
document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_PageContent_Content_scs_requestdate').onblur = function (e) {

var requestdate = new Date($('#ctl00_ctl00_PageContent_Content_scs_requestdate').val());
var dd = requestdate.getDate()+1;
var mm = requestdate.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = requestdate.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} 
if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} 
requestdate = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;    
$('#ctl00_ctl00_PageContent_Content_scs_deliverydate').val(requestdate);
```

It Works fine if the requestdate day + 1 is on the range of the given Month, but if the requestdate day is the last day of the given month and I add 1 to the day, the deliverydate field display mm/dd/yy which mean the date I set to the field is Invalid.

How can I check if the requestdate day is the last day of the Month and Set the delivery date to the right value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a a date to the date instead of adding it to the day of the month value, so that you can read the values from the desired date.

```
var requestdate = new Date($('#ctl00_ctl00_PageContent_Content_scs_requestdate').val());
requestdate.setDate(requestdate.getDate() + 1);
var dd = requestdate.getDate();
var mm = requestdate.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = requestdate.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}
requestdate = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
```

Comment: requestdate.setDate(requestdate.getDate() + 1); //do the Tricks!!
Works like a charm.
Thanks Arun